# Add row value in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, mysqli

I am trying to update a table product_desc and there are two columns `name` and `description`. I have a standard text for desc: `'Buy $name from us'`.

Now, I can simple write update query but I want to use the `$name` from `product_desc.name` field.

Is this possible by writing just the query?

```
UPDATE product_desc 
  SET description = "Buy $name from blah blah" 
  WHERE $name = product_desc.name where id > 0;
```

something like this.

Comment: Can you show the table's structure? also, concatenating data to a query is dangerous, use prepared statements instead. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use AND for more condition

```
UPDATE product_desc 
SET description = concat("Buy ", :name, "  from blah blah" )
where $name = product_desc.name 
AND id > 0;
```

anyway you should use a proper data binding and not use php var in sql code  ..

```
UPDATE product_desc 
SET description = "Buy $name from blah blah" 
where :name = product_desc.name 
AND id > 0;
```

**see for you db driver for use correct binding**

or as suggested  by  Patrick Q if youn just need add  the product name to description

```
UPDATE product_desc 
SET description = concat("Buy ", name  , " from blah blah" )
;
```

Comment: The way I read it, OP actually wants to use the value from the `name` column as part of the description. No variables or binding needed, just a concat on the fixed-text and the column reference.

Comment: missing paren  .. add.

Comment: @scaisEdge I have MariaDB and it says unexpected character near :name

Comment: you must use a proper binging  and not use the code with :name direcly  .. anyway check you the 3th suggestion is for your need  too

Comment: @scaisEdge tried this. It executes but nothing happens.

Comment: are you sure you have id > 0  and you have a valid content in name column?..answer updated  without where  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge yes I even tried id = 4 a specific one but it executes without updating

Comment: have you a valid name  .. and how is long the description column? .. anyway check better  .. if the query is executed  the column must be updated .. at lest with  "Buy  from blah blah"

Comment: @newbie756 What is the response from your db when you execute this command? And how are you executing it? Command line? Through a PHP script? A tool like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench?

Comment: @PatrickQ  This one worked UPDATE product_desc 
SET description = concat("Buy ", name  , " from blah blah" )
where id = 7;